# Impact of two bodies problem

Tags: physics, classical-mechanics

> A body of mass $M$ moving with a velocity $u$ collides with another of mass $m$ which rests on a table. Both the balls are perfectly elastic and smooth and the the body of $m$ is driven in a direction making an angle $\theta$ with the previous line of motion of $M$. Show that its velocity is $$\frac{2M}{M+m}u\cos{\theta}.$$

I have some doubt to understand the problem. It seams to me that the collision is direct (not oblique). 
Let after impact, $v_1$, $v_2$ are the velocities of bodies of masses $M$ and $m$ respectively.

I am unable to understand the line **"the the body of $m$ is driven in a direction making an angle $\theta$ with the previous line of motion of $M$"**

What will be the angles after the impact with the line of centers. Please help me.

**It seems to me that, I have to find $v_2$.**

I want to apply then the Newton's experimental law and conservation of linear momentum.

Comment: I do think that this question would better be suited in physics.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

The collision is oblique.$M$ comes in from point $A$, the impact is at $B$ and leaves on the way to $C$.  $m$ starts at $B$ and leaves on the way to $D$.  The vector to $E$ is the continuation of $M$'s initial motion.  $\theta$ is shown.  You need to apply momentum conservation in each axis as well as energy conservation.

[image]

Comment: Please check the Newton's experimental law 
$$v_1\cos{\phi}-v_2\cos{\theta}=-e(u-0)$$

and conservation of linear momentum
$$Mv_1\cos{\phi}+mv_2\cos{\theta}=Mu+0$$

Comment: $\phi$ is the angle of M with the line of centers (ie AE)

Comment: Your linear momentum equation is correct for the $x$ direction.  You need to write another for the $y$ direction and one for energy.  What is $e$?  It must be some function of the masses. I believe you are to derive the experimental law you quote.

Comment: $e$ is the coefficient of restitution. Here $e=1$, as the bodied are perfectly elastic.

Comment: Eliminating $\phi$ from the two equation, I get $v_2$ as $$v_2=\frac{2Mu}{M+m}\cdot \frac{1}{\cos{\theta}}$$. Please check where I am wrong.

Comment: That is exactly what you were asked to prove in the original question.  You have just moved the $u$ into the first fraction.  Nothing is wrong.

Comment: No, Please look at the answer carefully. 2nd fraction has $\frac{1}{\cos{\theta}}$ instead of ${ \cos{\theta}}$.

Comment: You are right.  Without seeing the derivation I can't see where you went wrong.  I would look back through your derivation for that term.  You probably moved it from one side to the other by multiplying and got it inverted at some point